# Mysql query insert using equals signs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This may be an easy questions but i am wondering if an "insert" sql statement can be writen with equals signs.

Example:  Right now my sql looks like this and works fine:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO people (
        id, 
        name, 
) VALUES (
        {$id},
        '{$name}',
```

)

So i was wondering if i can write the sql statement like this or something similar to this using = signs:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO people 
        id = {$id},
        name = '{$site_url}',
```

Thank you for any help.  I am just looking for an easier way to write this code especially when i have a lot of form fields.  Thanks.

Comment: See also the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

You have to use `SET`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO people 
    SET id = {$id},
    name = '{$site_url}'";
```

Comment: But don't forget that this is non-standard syntax and won't work on any other DBMS.

Comment: correct, as far as i know it will only work with MySQL... i found that out the hard way

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO people SET id={$id}.....
```

Comment: note that the INSERT/SET syntax would not be compatible with other SQL rdbms such as Postgre.

Comment: True, but since the OP is asking about MySQL, this isn't an issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
Please refer to the second syntax.

For your example, I think it would look like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO people
SET id={$id},
name={$name},
etc"
```